# PostMapping Spring boot annotation is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to spring boot and do not know why my @PostMapping is not working and leading to a white label error. Everything else works fine and I can add customers to the h2 database. However, once I add customers and go to URL localhost:8084/getdetails and type 1, a white label error occurs. However, the form in the ViewCustomers.jsp file is still displayed but cannot take in any input. The form should invoke toString() of the customer object and its fields.

Controller

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class FormController {
  @Autowired
  CustomerRepo repo;

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String details() {
    return "edureka";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/details")
  public String details(Customers customers) {
    repo.save(customers);
    return "edureka";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/getdetails")
  public String getdetails() {
    return "ViewCustomers";
  }

  @PostMapping("/getdetails")
  public ModelAndView getdetails(@RequestParam int cid) {
    System.out.println("here");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("Retrieve");
    Customers customers = repo.findById(cid).orElse(null);
    mv.addObject(customers);
    return mv;
  }
}
```

edureka.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Edureka Customers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="details">
        Enter Customer ID: <input type="text" name="cid"><br><br>
        Enter Customer Name: <input type="text" name="cname"><br><br>    
        Enter Customer Email Address: <input type="email" name="cemail"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ViewCustomer.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>View Customer Details</h1>
    <h2>Details as submitted as follows</h2>
    <form method="getdetails" action="post">
        <input type="number" name="cid"><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Retrieve.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Retrieve Customer Details</h1>
    <h2>Details as submitted as follows:</h2>
    <h5>${customers}</h5>
</body>
</html>
```

Customers.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customers {
  @Id
  private int cid;
  private String cname;
  private String cemail;

  public int getCid() {
    return cid;
  }

  public void setCid(int cid) {
    this.cid = cid;
  }

  public String getCname() {
    return cname;
  }

  public void setCname(String cname) {
    this.cname = cname;
  }

  public String getCemail() {
    return cemail;
  }

  public void setCemail(String cemail) {
    this.cemail = cemail;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Customers [cid=" + cid + ", cname=" + cname + ", cemail=" + cemail + "]";
  }
}
```

CustomerRepo interface
    package com.example.demo;

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CustomerRepo extends CrudRepository<Customers,Integer>{

}
```

SubmissionFormApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import com.example.demo.SubmissionFormApplication;

@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SubmissionFormApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(SubmissionFormApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SubmissionFormApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SubmissionForm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SubmissionForm</name>
    <description>First Spring Boot Web app</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: (1) [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) is already meta-annotated with `@ComponentScan` and an explicit declaration is not required for your case (2)  Setting the logging level to DEBUG ( example , `logging.level.root=INFO` ) in application.properties will give you more details on the reason for error. If still the issue cannot be resolved , please update the question with e logged error (3) A `post` request to `get` the details does not look like a correct approach.

Comment: If you are going to use the `@PostMapping` for some mapping, you should also use `@GetMapping` for the other one (for consistency and removing ambiguity)

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewCustomer.jsp` form's Method should have **method** as `post` and **action** as `get details`. The problem is in html and not spring.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Your Controller can be annotated like `@RestController` instead of just `@Controller`.
2. Your mappings for `POST` is `@PostMapping` - For consistency, I would recommend your mapping for `GET` to be `@GetMapping` - So I'd replace all `@RequestMapping` with `@GetMapping` (this removes ambiguity and improves readability as well)
3. The form in your `eureka.jsp`, needs to change the URL is posting to.  Instead of `action=details` it should point to `action=getdetails`
4. The form in your view `viewcustomer.jsp` has the action and the post switched (the method should be `POST` the action should be `getdetails`)

Answer (score 0):

The `@PostMapping("/getdetails")` maps to the path `"/getdetails"`. Such a mapping already exists. Try to map to another path in order to resolve this conflict.

Comment: You can actually map the same URL (i.e. `/getdetails`) to separate methods (i.e. `GET` or `POST`) so I doubt this is the issue